# What is the maximum hard disk size recognized by Amibios v1502?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

I have a Seagate Barracuda 500GB hard drive that the BIOS shows the size as being 0MB in compatibility mode, and 4.14GB in AHCI mode. My motherboard is an ASUS P7P55D-E PRO.

What is causing the disk's size to be wrong?

Is it possible my troubles are due to the BIOS not recognizing a disk this big? How do I find out the maximum disk size my BIOS will support?

Comment: What model/make is your motherboard?

Comment: Updated the detail into the article up top

Comment: Hmm, kind of surprising as it's a relatively new board. And the disk works in the OS?

Comment: nope. this is a new box i'm building; but i tried the disk on a neighbour's computer which also reported 0MB

Comment: So are you able to install anything on it or not?

Comment: Well, I wanted to install W7-64 on it ... when the installer said the disk size was too small I headed up here to superuser.com ; haven't tried to install aught else on it

Answer (score 0):

If the disk repeatedly clicks (might be rather quite), return it to the retailer. Its defective when it does not even know to report its size correcty to BIOS. This information is stored on the magnetic surface, so there must be a serious problem reading data - very bad for a hard disk.

Comment: No clicking ... but it's almost a week now I've been stooging around this issue; might as well begin consider an RMA now )+: